# How to catch ng-pattern in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, input

I have a example.

```
<input type="text" id="openDate" name="openDate" ng-model="ngModel" required="" ng-minlength="1" ng-maxlength="10" ng-pattern="/^[0-9,/]+$/">
```

when ng-pattern catch error it will draw red color on input element.

So I want to catch this error and show title message : "This field be fail format."

How to I can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) to catch it.

So, in your HTML, instead of using ng-pattern, you would make a new attribute. In this case, I called it ng-attr-mynewpattern.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="opendate" ng-minlength="1" ng-maxlength="10" ng-attr-mynewpattern="/^[0-9,/]+$/">
```

Then, add the directive. Notice, you strip off the "ng-attr". In the directive, I set the element and the pattern in the scope. This should probably change to something more robust, but I wanted to keep the example simple.

```
app.directive("mynewpattern", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
            scope.pattern = attrs.mynewpattern;
            scope.el = el;
        }
    };
});
```

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tonyzampogna/6Vj7p/